Do step-up and step-down converters violate Ohm's law?
I am talking specifically about DC step-up and step-down converters. If I have a certain circuit with a converter that would change the current and the voltage 2x, would not that mean that the resistance would have to change 4x ? And, in that case, would that even be possible considering that nothing in the circuit actually changes it (or does the converter mess with it somehow ?) ? I know that this is probably a weird misconception, but that just keeps bugging me.

Yes, impedance transformation does change the impedance with the square of the voltage. If you are talking about a perfect 2x upconverter, then it will have to transform the differential impedance of its power source also by a factor of 4. In practice we are usually giving up on efficiency to improve the stability of a power system.

Yes, transformers do not follow Ohm’s law. Nor do inductors, capacitors, transistors, batteries, and many other electronic components.
Ohm’s law is a law that describes only a fairly narrow class of materials and devices: resistors and conductors. Essentially everything else violates it.
An ideal transformer follows $V_1 N_2=V_2 N_1$ and $I_1 N_1=I_2 N_2$. This is different from Ohm’s law $V=IR$

But other answers told me that converters do change the resistance of the circuit, and therefore they do not violate ohm's law. So who is correct ?

@Keyakit see the update. Transformers follow different laws than resistors do.


If I have a certain circuit with a converter that would change the current and the voltage 2x, would not that mean that the resistance would have to change 4x ?

What resistance are you talking about?
If you have a (for example) 1000 ohm resistor loading the output of your converter, and the converter outputs 10 V, then Ohm's law tells us that the current through the resistor must be 10 mA.
If you then increase the voltage 2x by changing the design of the converter, it now outputs 20 V. And Ohm's law tells us that the current through the (1000 ohm) resistor is 20 mA, which is 2x the previous current.
What makes you say that the resistor value must change by 4x?
That said, there's no rule that says if you change your converter design to double the output voltage, the output current must also double. If the converter output is loaded by a (ideal or nearly ideal) resistor, then the current will double. If the converter output is loaded by some other device, then the current will follow the rules for that device, not Ohm's law (which is the rule for the I-V relationship of a resistor).

Thank you for your reply. What I meant was that if the voltage gets raised 2x, then the current should get lowered 2x (halved). But then what confuses me is why, if we make the circuit the same on both sides, the input and the output would work as if there was a difference in resistance. If the voltage increases 2x as in the case of step-up converters, then the current should be decreased 2x, and therefore the resulting resistance, according to Ohm's law, should be decreased 4x. So does it ? Or does the Ohm's law not apply here ? Or is there nothing about changing the current ?

Thank you again. So what you are saying, is that the load "draws" the same amount of power regardless of the voltage of the voltage source, so if I decrease the voltage 2x the current will follow to sort of keep up with the load's demand ? And the converter does not change anything but the voltage on its output side ?

@Keyakit, What voltage source? Please include a diagram in your question post. If you double the voltage across a resistor you quadruple the power the resistor consumes, so I don't know where you're getting "the load draws the same amount of power"? Now if you double the voltage applied to an ideal switching converter, then yes, the switching converter willl draw enough power to supply its load. Is that what you're asking about. When you say "the load", "the source", "the voltage" you need to clarify what you mean --- it's very common for a circuit to have several loads, sources, and voltages.
